# Requiring file with variable in URL

Tags: php

I'm using require_once to call a script that will echo back HTML for a the footer of each page.  I have each page submitting a variable in the URL for the PHP file to retrieve via $_GET, but because it doesn't see a file with the name of the full URL (including variable) it isn't working.  Any work arounds here?

**ERROR:**

```
Warning: require_once(footer/footer.php?page=homepage) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/05/10838405/html/index.php on line 434
```

If I remove the '?page=homepage' it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a variable

```
$page = 'homepage';
require_once 'footer/footer.php';
```

Then in our footer.php you can use `$page`

Comment: Wasn't aware it worked quite like that.  I'll accept yours when able because you were first.  Sorry Rick!

Answer (score 2):

GET parameters are a part of HTTP URLs – but the local file system of your server does “speak” HTTP.

So `footer/footer.php?page=homepage` would literally mean a *file* of that name (which does not exist, and the characters `?` and `=` are “illegal” as parts of a file/directory name in many file systems).

Since you are asking for a workaround – two easy possibilities (in both cases, only requiring the file by it’s actual name, `footer/footer.php`, of course):

1. you re-write the code inside that file to use a “normal” variable to decide what it should output – `$page`. (Although that might lead to problems with the variable scope, if `$_GET['page']` is used inside a function in that file.)
2. In your script that does the including, you set the GET parameter yourself – `$_GET['page'] = 'homepage';` before including the file. This is perfectly legal in PHP, from a syntactic standpoint – semantically, one might see that differently; and also it might lead to problems if in other code further down the line that GET parameter gets evaluated as well, and the value `homepage` is not expected in that context.

Comment: The second solution doesn't make sense in this instance, though the first one, which is what others recommended, does.  I wasn't aware previously declared variables passed on to called scripts.  It's a good thing I encountered this issue!  Who knows what atrocities could have otherwise befallen me in the future?

Answer (score 1):

require_once is a local include, its not going via a http request so things like query strings won't work.

do something like:

```
$page = 'homepage';
require 'footer.php'
```

$page will be available to footer.php

Edit: Beaten like a ginger stepchild

Additional Reading: [PHP Manual: Require Once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Comment: Also, don't use require once unless you have to, it adds overheads. not important in this case but best to get into good habits.

Comment: Tempted to accept your answer anyway because of your edit, but alas, I'll be accepting the first one.  Thanks though!

Comment: Yeah, I mean...do I HAVE to use it in this case?  No.  Is it convenient enough to use the same text on every page for the footer and just have a separate script handle the details that I'm willing to deal with the extra overhead on a small business site?  Yup. ;)

Comment: sorry thats not quite what I meant. require_once and require do almost exactly the same thing, except that require_once makes sure the file hasn't already been included somewhere else. in this case you probably have a very simple page so its extremely unlikely that you have accidentally included the footer twice so just use require not require_once

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having this problem is because `require_once` will look for a file called 'footer.php?page=homepage' which doesn't exist on your filesystem.  Romainberger's solution is good.